# AccountManager диалог запроса прав

Tags: android

Пытаюсь достать из AccountManager аккаунт Twitter. на сколько я знаю, при запросе данных аккаунта должен появиться диалог для подтверждения доступа приложения к данным пользователя. Но у меня диалог не появляется, а появляется только уведомление, при клике на которое уже появляется этот диалог. Не могу найти похожую проблему в интернете... Подскажите, что я делаю не так? Вот код:

```
new AsyncTask<String, String, String>() {
            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
                try {
                    getAccountData();

                } catch (AuthenticatorException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace(); 
                } catch (OperationCanceledException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();  
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace(); 
                }
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
                super.onPostExecute(s);
                onAccountRetrieved();
            }
        }.execute("");

private boolean getAccountData() throws AuthenticatorException, OperationCanceledException, IOException {
        try {
         AccountManager am = AccountManager.get(this);
         Account account = am.getAccountsByType("com.twitter.android.auth.login")[0];
            Bundle token = am.getAuthToken(account, "com.twitter.android.oauth.token", true, null, null).getResult();
            Bundle secret = am.getAuthToken(account, "com.twitter.android.oauth.token.secret", true, null, null).getResult();
            this.token = token.getString(AccountManager.KEY_AUTHTOKEN);
            this.secret = secret.getString(AccountManager.KEY_AUTHTOKEN);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема скорее всего была в том, что нужно использовать хендлер. Конкретнее - сделал точно как 
[тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6341164/twitter-authentication-through-androids-accountmanager-classes)